# git push heroku master is giving me an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, heroku

I have a react app i'm trying to deploy to heroku, However when I run git push heroku master, I'm receiving the error below. How can this be fixed please?

```
To https://git.heroku.com/getsoundtracks.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/getsoundtracks.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Heroku, but this error basically means that you are trying to push directly to a protected branch - `master`.

This is quite normal actually (even the default IIRC) for the master branch. You will probably need to do one of the following:

- create a "development" branch and push that to the remote and then merge that into master in Heroku (merge request or such?)
- Edit the master branch in Heroku and set it to `unprotected`

Comment: When pushing to Heroku, Heroku checks if the project is compatible with the buildpack ([for nodejs buildpack this gets executed](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/blob/master/bin/detect)). Then it [compiles](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/blob/master/bin/compile) the project. If the first step fails (or maybe both, idk) it will say pre-receive hook declined.  
Also if it can't detect what buildpack the project is using it will also throw pre-receive hook declined.